# Nuxtjs авторизация

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase, nuxt.js

Всем привет, пытаюсь в nuxt сделать авторизацию через firebase, столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

В middleware который повешен на основной layout я проверяю авторизацию

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
export default function({ store, redirect }) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("have");
    } else {
      redirect("/login");
    }
  });
}
```

Почему перед редиректом успевает отрендерится страница? и только потом происходит редирект если пользователь не залогинен

p.s использую SPA mode

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего ты в middleware не ждешь выполнения onAuthStateChanged функции т.к она асинхронная. Допусти что вместо указанного тобой кода будет setTimeout() и много должно стать на свои места. Посмотри возвращает ли данная функция промис и если возвращает то верни ее из мидлвары.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware